# Oracle AIX: opatchauto wasn't able to run the command "" because 'bash' command could not be found on the current platform

Tags: oracle, bash, aix, oracle12c

I'm trying to install Oracle 12c patches on a system running AIX. The binaries and database are both installed and running, but I'm running into issues now and can't seem to find a fix.

I'm exporting the location of `opatchauto` to the PATH variable, and running:

opatchauto apply (location of opatchauto that is in $PATH) -analyze

opatchauto starts normally, but then fails with the message:

```
opatchauto wasn't able to run the command "ORACLE_HOME=/db/opt00/oracle/product/12.1.0 /db/opt00/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin/srvctl stop home -o /db/opt00/oracle/product/12.1.0 -f -s /db/opt00/oracle/product/12.1.0/OracleHome-1c2d7f9a-7e5d-49b8-bea4-08b559868cc1.stat" because 'bash' command could not be found on the current platform.
For more details, please refer to the log file "/asm/opt00/oracle/product/12.1.0/cfgtoollogs/opatchauto/20834538/opatch_gi_2015-08-10_08-13-44_analyze.debug.log".
```

bash (`sh`) is in `/bin/` and is in `$PATH` as well, so I'm wondering if anyone else has experience with this issue and/or ideas on how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: `bash` is not the same as `sh`, so if you have `sh` and not `bash` that could be the problem

Comment: ah, I see. I was told that it wouldn't matter, but bash isn't there, so that looks like a possible culprit.....

Answer (score 0):

As Eric pointed out this is true. 
In fact you will find that the default shell for AIX is `ksh` in most cases. So make sure your in the right shell when you start it.
It might also be a idea to add `#!/bin/sh` to the beginning of a script if this is how its called, as this will ensure starts inside the correct shell regardless of your own environment variables.